# EditText Validation setError not working, getting crashed

Tags: android

I'm doing the check for my two EditText field editNumber1 and editNumber2.
I'm trying to display if the check perform fails.
I'm not able to display the error and the application crashes.
here is the sample code can any one suggest?

```
if ((editNumber1.getText().length() == 0) || (editNumber1.getText().toString() == " ") || 
    (editNumber2.getText().length() == 0) || (editNumber2.getText().toString() == " "))
{    
    editNumber1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editNumber1.requestFocus();         
    editNumber1.setError("Some inputs are empty");
}
```

Comment: First of all use string.equals(otherString) to compare strings.

What is the error? can you post it?

Comment: this code (editNumber1.getText().toString() == " ") doesnt mean the edittext is empty, while this is editNumber1.getText().toString() == "") no space between quotations.

Comment: i guess that this line "editNumber1.requestFocus();" have error. remove body of if statement and put a Toast and try again.

Comment: There are two activities i'm performing here. 1st the editNumber1 and editNumber 2 should not be blank by gettting the length and checking that length is not zero. and 2nd They should be not be blank value.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all use this good utilities  `StringUtils.isNotBlank( string_to_compare );`
this method return `false` if the `string_to_compare` is:

> - null,
> - empty (""),
> - blank (" ")

then try to use a break point in the lines below to see when the crash occurs

```
 editNumber1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
 editNumber1.requestFocus();         
 editNumber1.setError("Some inputs are empty");
```